# Why am I getting ∫(3x+1)^3dx as ((3x + 1)^12 )/18?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

[Integration of  ∫(3x+1)^3dx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0cJL.jpg)

I have no clue why I am getting the integration of $\int(3x+1)^3dx$ as $((3x + 1)^{12} )/18$. The differentiation of $(3x+1)^3$ is done correctly, but I'm still getting the wrong answer.

Comment: Those two are not even related. Where is tje cosine coming from?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! PLease consider using MathJax to typeset mathematical expressions in your posts. Additionally, as is currently written your question lacks proper context, motivation and your attempts at a solution. In fact the solution you posted as an image is irrelevant to your question. Please fix these or else it is unlikely you'll get an answer at MSE.

Comment: My apologies. I am a new user and don't know how to use MathJax. I had mistakenly entered the wrong question. My sincerest condolences.

Comment: Where is the $(\ldots)^{12}$ in your image?

Comment: When you finally calculate $\int t^3\frac{d\left(t^3\right)}{9t^2}$, that $9t^2$ denominator is not a constant and will not stay intact.

Comment: Check my solution for the appropriate result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets integrate

$$I=\int (3x+1)^3 dx.$$

Let $u=3x+1$ then $du=3dx$ (so $dx=\frac{1}{3} du$) thus

\begin{align}
I&= \frac{1}{3} \int u^3 du\\
&= \frac{1}{12} u^4 + C \\
&=\frac{1}{12}(3x+1)^4+C
\end{align}

here $C$ is the constant of integration.